# is wrapping input element by label tag valid?

Tags: html, label

Do we need to use always the for attribute to associate input element to a label or keeping input element inside the label also fine?

I want to know what is the best practice and whether it is valid to wrap like that.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 2):

It is valid to wrap `input` inside `label`, and by the specifications, it associates the label text with the control. However, browser support is better for the approach where the association is explicit with `id` and `for` attribute, so doing so is the best practice.

Comment: Which browsers don't support association by containment that do support association by idref?

Comment: @BoltClock, not many, probably just ancient browsers like IE 6, but I would be more worried about (old versions of) assistive software.

Answer (score 1):

They work exactly the same. Also, the standard accepts both :
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: w3schools is not perfect, but it's acurate at this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL